# Swipe to delete reveals label that should be hidden in cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I been having a lot of issues with trying to implement an expandable cell into my app. The problem at the moment is that although my code works as intended for expanding and collapsing the cell, it shows the content that should be hidden when swiping to delete which looks terrible.

Another issue is that when I tap a navigation button to segue away from the tableview, one of the cells expand. Also, when tapping a cell, it seems to loose the dividing line at the top until a different cell is tapped. (These issues are more minor. The first issue mentioned is more major.)

This is my code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
var selectedRowIndex: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: -1, inSection: 0)

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

This is my code in heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    cellHeight = 68
    if tableView != self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView {
        if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row {
            if cellTapped == false {
                cellTapped = true
                cellHeight = 141
                return 141
            } else {
                cellTapped = false
                cellHeight = 68
                return 68
            }
        }
    }
    return 68
}
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if cellHeight == 141 {
    cell.notesLabel.hidden = false
    println("False")
} else if cellHeight == 68 {
    cell.notesLabel.hidden = true
    println("True")
}
```

At the moment, this code just seems to make cell.notesLabel *always* hidden as cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't seem to be called when tapping the cell.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue or a better implementation? I'm sure there must be an easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking into auto resizing cells.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

As your content changes you must reload the cell and animate it, but I think this would be a better implementation of it using:

```
reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [AnyObject], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

It sounds like you have a lot of gestures going on and that is probably contributing to your problems. With the draggable cells, make sure it is the contentView that the pan gesture is changing the offset of, or if you have all of your cell's content in a view, make sure it is applied to that view.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in a solution to this problem, here is my solution.

The variable selectedRowIndex keeps track of the indexPath.row of the last row the user has tapped.

label1, label2 and label3 are hidden by the being outside of the bounds of the cell when it is not in its expanded state.

EditActionsForRowAt is called when the user swipes to delete, and so at this point I hide the labels that are currently not displayed to the user as they are out of the bounds of the cell. There are some if statements to check whether the labels should be hidden or not.

```
var selectedRowIndex = -1

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
        return 95 //Expanded
    }
    return 50 //Not expanded
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    if selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row {
        selectedRowIndex = -1
    } else {
        selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
        cell.label1.isHidden = false
        cell.label2.isHidden = false
        cell.label3.isHidden = false
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row != selectedRowIndex {
        cell.label1.isHidden = true
        cell.label2.isHidden = true
        cell.label3.isHidden = true
    }
    return nil
}
```

Hope that helps someone out!

Dan